# Kendo Grid with DateTime shows incorrect time in app, but correct in localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, localhost

List of objects which includes DateTime property from SQL database being displayed incorrectly.

View has Kendo grid with a column which displays the time returned from the DB/Controller.

The time is currently showing incorrectly in prod, but shows up correctly through localhost.

Break point at the controller just before the view confirms time is correct.

Verified all code is merged (so code from app is same as code used to debug).

```
// Get call inside controller
public JsonResult GetUpcomingEvents()
{
   // actual list is coming from DB
   var results = new List<UpcomingEvents>();
   // break point on line below, confirmed time is correct here
   return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

// Model 
public class UpcomingEvents
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }   
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }   
}

//View 
function getUpcomingEvents() {
 $.ajax({
   url: 'myUrl',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (returnValue) {
    setKendoGrid();
   }
});
}

function setKendoGrid() {
    $("#myKendoGrid").kendoGrid(
    {
        columns:
        [
            { field: "EventName", title: "NAME" },
            { template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(StartDate), 'MM/dd/yy<br />hh:mm tt')#", field: "StartDate", title: "Start" },
            { template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(EndDate), 'MM/dd/yy<br />hh:mm tt')#", field: "EndDate", title: "End" }
        ],
        dataSource: { data: window.gridData, pageSize: 5 }
    });
}
```

Code on the server displaying the incorrect time (believe UTC). 
Code through debugger/localhost is displaying the correct time.

Comment: Is the timezone set on the server the same as the timezone on localhost? That could account for the discrepancy.

Comment: That did seem to be the fix! Your comment helped me to look and compare. Thank you Kei

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the culture like:

```
<script>
    kendo.culture('en-US');
</script>
```

change `'en-US'` to the culture you like.